# Error in HTML code

Tags: html

**This is a part of a practice exam that I am taking. In this question I am supposed to find the bugs in the HTML code.

I am getting the message:   "Lists and images: Wrong answer"
Can you see the bug that I am missing in the lists?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome! Here you can find the following things:</p>
    <ol>
      <em><li><a href="#logo">Company's logo</a></li></em>
      <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
    </ol>

    <h1>Company's logo</h1>
    <p>Company uses the following logos:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>New logo:  <img src="new_logo.gif">  </li>
      <li>Old logo:  <img src="old_logo.gif">  </li>
    </ul>

    <h1>List of employees</h1>


    <table>

      <thead>    <!--Headers go inside of table!-->
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </thead>

      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Williams</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To answer the question that was asked, yes.

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712254/error-in-html-code/51712299#51712299) @Andri for a detailed explanation 

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few errors in your code which, however, can be easily sniffed out, if you use the [W3C HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options):

1. List elements, aka `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements, can't have children other than `<li>` but you have set an `<em>`. Put that `<em>` inside `<a>` and you're fine.

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="#logo"><em>Company's logo</em></a></li>
  <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
</ol>
```

2. Your images must have an `alt` attribute specified except under certain conditions, according to the [W3C HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options).

```html
<ul>
  <li>New logo: <img src="new_logo.gif" alt="new logo"></li>
  <li>Old logo: <img src="old_logo.gif" alt="old logo"></li>
</ul>
```

3. The structure of your table is wrong. `<th>` elements are cell elements and must reside in `<tr>` as much as `<td>` elements do. Also, since you've specified a `<thead>` element, it's a good idea to use a `<tbody>` as well.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Williams</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When you make the aforementioned changes to your code, your validation should be clean, apart from maybe a warning, because of not having specified the `lang` attribute of the `<html>` element. Set `<html lang="en">` and your code will be perfect.